# Function no called on jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm having some problems with the a4jFunction. I need to eliminate data from dataTable, the getters and setters are working, the PopUp pannel works fine, but the function is not called.

See this code:

```
<h:panelGrid id="panelGridDataT" style="margin-left:300px">
        <h:form id="form" >
            <rich:dataTable
                style="margin-left:70px;height:200px; width:500px;overflow:auto"
                value="#{ListSelectBean.listUser}" var="_tblUser" iterationStatusVar="it"
                id="table" rows="5">
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#</f:facet>
                     #{it.index}
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{_tblUser.name}" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">User Name</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{_tblUser.username}" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Role</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{_tblUser.roles}" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column style="width:40px">
                <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                    <a4j:commandLink style="padding:10px" execute="@this" render="@none" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.show()">
                        <h:graphicImage value="/img/delete.gif" style="width:20px;height:20px" alt="delete" />
                    <!--  <a4j:param value="#{it.index}"    assignTo="#{ListSelectBean.currentUserIndex}" />--> 
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ListSelectBean.deleteUser}" value="#{_tblUser}" />
                    </a4j:commandLink>
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column style="width:40px">
                <f:facet name="header">Edit</f:facet>
                <a4j:commandLink style="padding:10px" render="editGrid" action="#{ListSelectBean.asingEdit()}" execute="@this" onclick="#{rich:component('editPane')}.show() ">
                        <h:graphicImage value="/img/edit.gif" style="width:20px;height:20px" alt="edit"  />
                        <a4j:param value="#{it.index}" assignTo="#{ListSelectBean.currentUserIndex}" />
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ListSelectBean.editedUser}" value="#{_tblUser}" />
                </a4j:commandLink>
                </rich:column>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <rich:dataScroller page="#{ListSelectBean.page}" style="margin-left:40px"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Add New" id="Add" style="margin-left:40px" >
                        <rich:componentControl target="New_User" operation="show"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </f:facet>
            </rich:dataTable>

            <a4j:jsFunction name="DeleteUser" id="DeleteUser" action="#{ListSelectBean.DeleteUser()}" render="@all" execute="@all"
                 />

            <rich:popupPanel id="confirmPane" autosized="true">
                     Are you sure you want to delete the row?
                <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.hide(); return false;" render="form" />
                <a4j:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="DeleteUser();" oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.hide();">
                <a4j:param value="#{it.index}"  assignTo="#{ListSelectBean.currentUserIndex}" />    
                    <f:ajax render="@all" execute="@all" />
                </a4j:commandButton>
            </rich:popupPanel>

            <rich:popupPanel id="statPane" autosized="true">
                <h:graphicImage value="/images/ai.gif" alt="ai" />
                Please wait...
            </rich:popupPanel>

            <rich:popupPanel header="Edit User Details" id="editPane"
                domElementAttachment="form" width="400" height="170">
                <h:panelGrid columns="4" id="editGrid">
                    <h:outputText value="Name" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{ListSelectBean.nwname }" />
                    <h:outputText value="username" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{ListSelectBean.nwusername}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Pasword" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{ListSelectBean.nwpassword}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Email" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{ListSelectBean.nwemail}" />

                </h:panelGrid>
                <a4j:commandButton value="Store" action="#{ListSelectBean.storeUser}" render="table" execute="editPane" 
                style="position: absolute; right: 10px; bottom: 10px" 
                oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null}) {#{rich:component('editPane')}.hide();}" />
                <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" style="position: absolute; right: 60px; bottom: 10px" 
                    onclick="#{rich:component('editPane')}.hide(); return false;" />
            </rich:popupPanel>

        </h:form>


    </h:panelGrid>
```

There is a lot code, I need focus on:

```
<rich:column style="width:40px">
            <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                <a4j:commandLink style="padding:10px" execute="@this" render="@none" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.show()">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/img/delete.gif" style="width:20px;height:20px" alt="delete" />
                <!--  <a4j:param value="#{it.index}"    assignTo="#{ListSelectBean.currentUserIndex}" />--> 
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ListSelectBean.deleteUser}" value="#{_tblUser}" />
                </a4j:commandLink> </rich:column>
```

the parameters   works fine, but this next doesn't:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="DeleteUser" id="DeleteUser" action="#{ListSelectBean.DeleteUser()}" render="@all" execute="@all"
                 />

            <rich:popupPanel id="confirmPane" autosized="true">
                     Are you sure you want to delete the row?
                <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.hide(); return false;" render="form" />
                <a4j:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="DeleteUser();" oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.hide();">
                <a4j:param value="#{it.index}"  assignTo="#{ListSelectBean.currentUserIndex}" />    
                    <f:ajax render="@all" execute="@all" />
                </a4j:commandButton>
            </rich:popupPanel>
```

Ihis is the bean if anyone needs it:

```
private TblUser editedUser;
private TblUser deleteUser;
private int currentUserIndex;
private int UserRows;
private int page = 1;
private String Nwemail;
private String Nwname;
private String Nwpassword;
private String Nwroles;
private String Nwusername;
private String Nwtokenid; 
private short Nwuserid;
private Long Nwuseroleid;

@DataModel
private List<TblUser> ListUser;

@DataModelSelection("ListUser")
@Out (required=false)
private TblUser selected;


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Factory(value="ListUser")


public List<TblUser> selectedList(){

    ListUser = null;

    if (ListUser == null){


        try{
        ListUser=entityManager.createQuery("select u from TblUser u").getResultList();
        }catch(NoResultException e) {
            System.out.print("Error"+e.getMessage());
        }   
        }
        return ListUser;
    }



public void DeleteUser()
{
    try{
    entityManager.createQuery("Delete TblUser where userid = :userid")
    .setParameter("userid", deleteUser.getUserid())
    .executeUpdate();
    //refreshPage();
    }
    catch (NoResultException e)
    {
        System.out.print("error: "+ e.getMessage());
    }}
```

I will appreciate if anyone helps me!

Comment: Do you have getter and setter for `TblUser deleteUser`? Can you check if deleteUser object exists and is correct in DeleteUser method?

Comment: In `a4j:jsFunction` change `action` attribute to `action="#{ListSelectBean.DeleteUser}"`.

Comment: Have you check if there are any other DeleteUser() javascript functions defined on the page (try changing the name)? Also is the a4jFunction inside a form?

Comment: `a4j:commandButton` has `render` attribute. You don't need `f:ajax` in commandButton if it for rendering only.

Comment: @VasilLukach yes i have getters and setters

 `public TblUser getDeleteUser() {
  return deleteUser;
 }

 public void setDeleteUser(TblUser deleteUser) {
  this.deleteUser = deleteUser;
 }`

i change action="#{ListSelectBean.DeleteUser()}" for action="#{ListSelectBean.DeleteUser}" and doesn't works.

Comment: @DaveB there is not any other function with same name, i also change before to "DeloterUsera" thinking on that and doesn't work

in the code you can see that it is into `<h:form id="form" >`